# Awaited Promises created Array.map return <pending>

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise

I'm using google-cloud-functions to trigger thumbnail creation on uploading a file to Google cloud storage.

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {

     // Removed code not relevant to the problem

     // Download file from bucket.
     await file.download({destination: tempLocalFile});

     const uploadPromises = sizes.map(async size => {
        const tempLocalThumbFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), thumbFilePath);

        // Generate a thumbnail using Sharp.
        await sharp(tempLocalFile).resize(width, height).toFile(tempLocalThumbFile);
        console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempLocalThumbFile);

        return thumbFile.getSignedUrl(config);
  });

    // Get the Signed URLs for the original image.
    const results = await Promise.all([
        uploadPromises,
        file.getSignedUrl(config),
    ]);

    console.log(results[0]);
});
```

What I would expect the last console.log to output is an array of size 4, where each element contains the callback of the getSignedurl() function. Instead what I now get each time, is an array of size 4 where all elements are  promises.

Since I'm already awaiting the Promise.all() what have I done wrong to end up with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `uploadPromises` in the `Promise.all`:

```
const results = await Promise.all([
   ...uploadPromises,
   file.getSignedUrl(config),
]);
```

The issue is that `uploadPromises` is already an array, and you were passing it as an element of another array. By using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), you expand `uploadPromises` array into its elements.